# Apache Ignite takes forever to save values on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, ignite

I am using using Apache Ignite with Spark to save results from Spark, however, when I execute saveValues, it takes very long time and the computer's CPU and fan speed goes insane. I have 3GHz CPU and 16 GB memory.

I have an RDD in which I map the final DataFrame in it:

```
val visitsAggregatedRdd :RDD[VisitorsSchema] = aggregatedVenuesDf.rdd.map(....)
println("COUNT: " + visitsAggregatedRdd.count().toString())
visitsCache.saveValues(visitsAggregatedRdd)
```

The total count of rows is 71 which means Spark has already done processing data and it is quite small; 71 rows each one is small object with few numbers and very short strings. So why 'visitsCache.saveValues' is taking this infinite time and processing!?

Comment: Thread dump would be useful in understanding with what threads are busy.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem in Spark Dataframe partitions. Spark was saving those 71 rows were saved in 6000 partitions! A simple solution is to reduce the number of partitions before saving in Ignite:

```
df = df.coalesce(1)
```